Visual Studio published website gets error "Type 'JObject' is not defined" when page is loaded on server
This works in Visual Studio.
It does not work on Windows 2016 Server Core running IIS 10.
When published, there are no issues.
Run the website on the server, I receive the error Type 'JObject' is not defined..
Code line: Dim parsejson As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
All imports are there.
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

The Bin folder contains.
Newtonsoft.Json (Version # 13.0.3.27908) But without the .dll extension.
I moved over the Newtonsoft.Json.dll file. Even though they are the same size, Windows does not see them as the same, as Newtonsoft.Json is considered a .json file.
I thought maybe registering the .dll file with gacutil -i Newtonsoft.Json.dll would resolve the issue, but it is not registerable.
When run, it adds it to the cache.
But when running gacutil -l Newtonsoft.Json.dll
I get Invalid file or assembly name
So, it is unregisterable.
I added this to the web.config, but the issue is still the same.
(Got this code form here)
I am assuming I did the oldVersion and newVersion correctly. As the NewtonSoft dll is version 13.0.3.27908
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.3" newVersion="13.0.3" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime> 

I wanted to add this as the code I am using.
(From SO)
VB.NET Code To Parse Child Node Of JSON (Second code at the bottom)
I am not using [brackets] only {curly brackets} only.
Example of the JSON
{"data":
{"id":3,"name":"true red","year":2002,"color":"#BF1932","pantone_value":"19-1664"}
,"support":
{"url":"https://reqres.in/#support-heading","text":
"To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"}}

The code I am using.
 Imports System.Net
    Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
    
    Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
            Dim json As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://reqres.in/api/products/3")
            Dim parsejson As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
            Dim thename = parsejson.SelectToken("data.name").ToString()
            txt1.Text = "Name Is " + thename
        End Sub
    End Class

I am not using [brackets] only {curly brackets} only.

I've never seen this methodology for parsing json objects with newtonsoft; what's wrong with Dim parseJson As [class] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<class>(json)?

Hey, Ortund. Can you provide a working example of parsing a URL with what you have provided here?

Let me know if this helps you and I'll post it as an answer https://dotnetfiddle.net/j8LtBC

I just noticed something as well. We cannot have [ Brackets]. Curly Brackets are only allowed. I see that you took code from the first code instead of the second code, which is this one "VB.NET Code To Parse Child Node Of JSON" (Updating)

Also, this is for a website, not an app. How would I do this under a button?

I got it running on VS, but it does not run on a website. 'JsonConvert' is not declared. ---- Just like this topic, it gives, Type 'JObject' is not defined.  I'm stuck. They don't want to run from a website.

Make sure your website references Newtonsoft.Json... but I see this wasn't your issue. Glad you got it sorted though!

I had the same issue.
In IIS, Right-click on the folder from which the script is running.
Choose: Convert to Application.
Refresh the website in your browser, and everything should be working.
